# Prevent direct access to page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to prevent direct access to an html page that has downloads.  I want to force the user to login from a separate page.
Currently I am running a simple rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.example.com/this-page.html$ 
RewriteRule this-download-page.html - [F,NC]
```

This works great in everything other than ie11 and down.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?